# Count time between characters on input

Tags: javascript

I need to determine if the input has been made by a barcode scanner and not allow any more characters to be input in the field.

Since my scanner generates a `keypress`, I had the idea of getting the time between the first `x` input characters- getting the average and if the average is a humanly impossible, it would lock the field after the last character.

I am very new to JS, so help with any step of this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this solution:

```
document.body.onkeydown = function () {
 var time = this._time;
 var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
 if (time) console.log('time: ' + (timestamp - time));  
 this._time = timestamp;
}
```

Comment: hmm, this looks like something I could use but I get `NaN` in the console

Comment: warning this does not account for daylight saving time.

Answer (score 1):

Barcode scanners can be configured to have additionnal characters added before and after the scan. For example, if the code reads "5858445", the peripheral might return "@5858445/". Some configuration might also add the white space characters CR, LF or both.

Check the configuration of the hardware you are using, and, if you can, look at the manual.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know this. I will look into this, thanks!